# UnicodeDecodeError 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0

Tags: python

I have a code that goes recursively through some folders, in the way of

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(str(rootdir)):
```

Running the program I find the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 37: invalid start byte`.

Have changed the direction of `rootdir` to see when the error starts and have found some folders within the path I actually want to use that are completely fine and some that return the error, but the thing is all subdirectories either only have folders or have basically the same files, so I dont know where the error is coming from or how to fix it.

Please help.

The error appears in a line where I use an outside package but the package is imported fine, code is fine and it works when the unicode error doesn't appear. The line code imports a .xml file in the folder, is that file the one with the problem? (shouldn't since they are all created with the same program and if one is wrong then all should be wrong, not a few)

edit: to actually test my code youd have to install pymatgen (you could with pip) and get a `vasprun.xml` file. Highly unprobable, hence why I didnt put it at the beginning.

Code (last line with the error)

```
from pymatgen.electronic_structure.dos import CompleteDos, add_densities, Dos
from pymatgen.electronic_structure.core import Spin, Orbital
from pymatgen.io.vasp.outputs import Vasprun, Procar
vasprun = Vasprun(root+"/vasprun.xml")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "an.py", line 196, in <module>
vasprun = Vasprun(root+"/vasprun.xml")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/outputs.py", line 383, in __init__
self.update_potcar_spec(parse_potcar_file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/outputs.py", line 829, in update_potcar_spec
potcar = get_potcar_in_path(os.path.split(self.filename)[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/outputs.py", line 813, in get_potcar_in_path
pc = Potcar.from_file(os.path.join(p, fn))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/inputs.py", line 1704, in from_file
fdata = reader.read()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/codecs.py", line 314, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 37: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Please show the entire error message and all relevant code.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and edit your question to add things like your actual code (or preferably a [MCVE]), the precise exception you're getting, the line you're getting it at, etc.

Comment: i put the example but doubt it will be helpful

Comment: ( Does not look like [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) )

Comment: What's much more improbable is anyone being able to help you without you telling them the context of your problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: The file vasprun.xml that is distributed with pymatgen is not utf8 encoded, incidentally - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`. Perhaps yours isn't either, which easy to check.

Comment: pvg, it is encoded just as you said, can I change the encoding of the vasprun.xml by changing that line?

Comment: The change you need to make is to change your code to use utf8. Alternatively, open your file in a decent text editor and then save it as utf8 encoded.

Comment: I already tried putting `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` instead of the default one and the error still appears, is that how you are supposed to change the encoding?

Comment: changing the encoding there doesn't change the encoding of the file. It doesn't do anything at all other than changing a string in your file. You should either a) tell whatever library you are using the encoding is not utf8. Or, re-encode the file as utf8.

Answer (score 0):

The file is apparently not UTF-8 encoded. If it has an XML declaration that specifies UTF-8 (or does not specify an encoding), then you need to replace it. If there is no XML declaration, you should try adding one.
A correct XML declaration will need to specify the actual character set, probably `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>`, or possibly some other ISO encoding.

Comment: it says `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`, can I change the econding to UTF-8 by just replacing the encoding line?

Comment: Tried changing it by just replacing the line and the error still appears.

Comment: Something is clearly trying to decode the file as utf8 when it is not.  From what I can see, it is the `reader` object used in "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/inputs.py"